# Asp.net event when user enters a web site based on cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a website with different languages. Each time user change a language a save it in database.
When user enters web site based on cookie (without login), I want to check his last selection in DB and redirect accordingly.
Each language of the website has its own copy on IIS, and can navigate inside itself. So the first launch is what matters.

In which event should I put my code?

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Load()` will be fine but I'd rather check if the page is being post back to prevent unnecessary roundtrips.

Not sure about the exact coding but, it is done by putting :

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
    // Your cookie reading code here
}
```

Comment: Putting it in Page_Load() of page is unnecessary roundtrips. Is there some global function? Like Session_Start, but I can't redirect from there..

Comment: Not, if you check roundtrips. This is what I try to mean by "**check the page is being post back**". So you will do it only once, while the page is being loaded for the first time.

Comment: Thanks, it will save number of DB accesses. But still it will go to DB on every page, even if it is not postback. I wonder, if I can do it only once for each Session.